# Using ts function to build time related plot

Tags: r, time-series

I have following dataset where the timestamp column is in `[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"`

```
8       73      794   4927          4910       0       1753     4       0 2006-06-11 04:43:56          2          N
9       73     1744   4929          4928       0        146     9       0 2006-06-11 04:47:24          4          N
10      73     1520   4930          4913       0       2401     4       0 2006-06-11 04:47:54          5          N
11      73     1744   4931          4929       0        461   315       0 2006-06-11 04:49:37          6          N
12      73     1743   4933          4925       0        113    45       0 2006-06-11 04:52:12          7          N
13      73     1744   4934          4931       0       1248   787       0 2006-06-11 04:58:22          8          N
14      73     1744   4936          4934       0       1268    20       0 2006-06-11 05:01:11          9          N
15      73     1745   4938          4937       2        720    53       0 2006-06-11 05:06:56         11          N
16      73     1744   4939          4936       0       1290    22       0 2006-06-11 05:14:35         12          N
17      73      605   4940          3072       3        436   367       0 2006-06-11 05:21:44         13          N
18      73     1936   5734          5731      10        531   133       0 2006-08-21 19:55:50         19          N
19      73     1936   5735          5734      10        502   -29       0 2006-08-21 19:56:31         20          N
20      73     1745   7808          5692       2        746    23       0 2007-11-22 22:09:17         21          N
```

I am trying to use the ts function to get a plot between date column and column 6 but when I try to convert the dataframe into ts column: I get the following error:

```
Error in attr(data, "tsp") <- c(start, end, frequency) : 
  invalid time series parameters specified
```

This is how I tried to convert the df into ts object

```
df.ts <- ts(data=df.old$timestamp, frequency=12, start=c(2006,6), end=c(2007,12))
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'ts' package expects regular time series and it seems that you have here an irregular time series.
You can use package 'zoo' or 'lubridate' witch handles regular and irregular time series.